# How to integrate mobail Metamask or any cryptocurrency wallet with mobile browser?

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have been looking for the way of integrating mobile Metamask or any cryptocurrency with mobile browser, not with internal built-in mobile browser in Wallets.

If I correctly remember it, I have seen that some website allows users to connect their Metamask on mobile browser.

Basically, when I clicked the "connect" button on that website, the mobile Metamask pop up and "connect" my wallet address, or sometimes it said Open you app store linked to Metamask on the app store, in that case, it does not work well.

Would you please let me know this ?